# C#.net 4 parallel programming

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I'm reading a book called Pro .NET 4 Parallel Programming in C# by Adam Freeman. In Chapter 2 page 13 it talks about using `Task<int>` to return a result by using `task1.Result` to wait for it to finish. I don't understand why `task2` has to wait for `task1` to finish. They are on different threads.

It's something like below:

```
Task<int> task1 = new Task<int>(() => { ... ; return sum });
task1.Start();
Console.WriteLine("Result 1: {0}", task1.Result);

Task<int> task2 = new Task<int>(() => { ... ; return sum });
task2.Start();
Console.WriteLine("Result 2: {0}", task2.Result);
```

If I move to following line to the bottom it seems like `task1` still executes first no matter how many times I tried.

```
Console.WriteLine("Result 1: {0}", task1.Result);
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The task that actually finishes first -- that is, hits its return statement first -- is, formally, unpredictable. They can finish their work before you accept their Results.

If the work your sample tasks do is not very large, it stands to reason that task1 will finish first even if you don't accept its Result (or in Java threading lingo, join it) first.  That's because you Started it first.

Presumably you somehow know that task1 finished first.  Is there a Console.WriteLine buried in the code for your tasks?  If so, keep in mind that the Console subsystem serializes operations, so the first of your tasks to use it will do so completely before the second one can start. Think of it this way: your two tasks race to Console, and the winner takes all.

task1 has an unfair advantage in this race, because it's off and running before your main thread even starts constructing task2 with your second `new`.

Answer (score 3):

`Task.Result` blocks until the `Task` completes.

It has to in order to have a result to return!

So, in your first example, `task2` is not even started until `task1` has completed.

If you move `task1.Result` to the bottom, it is indeterminate which task completes first, but your `Console.WriteLine` statements will execute in sequential order.

Comment: Nicholas, thanks for replying. I can understand task.Result will wait until task finishes. If task1 has already started, I cannot start another Task(thread) to execute? There is another example like below:   foreach(string msg in messages) { Task tsk = new Task(obj => printMsg(obj), msg); tsk.Start();}. Those tasks inside the foreach loop execute in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [task.Wait()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd235635.aspx) method.

```
        Task<int> task1 = new Task<int>(() => { int sum = 0; return sum; });
        task1.Start();
        task1.Wait();
        Console.WriteLine("Result 1: {0}", task1.Result);

        Task<int> task2 = new Task<int>(() => { int sum = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Sum(); return sum; });
        task2.Start();
        task1.Wait();
        Console.WriteLine("Result 2: {0}", task2.Result);
```

Comment: It should give the same result but it is much easier to read since you explicitly "wait".

Answer (score 0):

"Console.WriteLine("Result 1: {0}", task1.Result);" can't run until task1 finishes, so it waits/blocks.

While the tasks do run independent of each other, the calling thread calls the console.writeline in a sequential order. The results of those two tasks are forced to be in-order.

Answer (score 0):

> `Task task1 = new Task(() => { ... ; return sum });
>
>    task1.Start();
>  
>    Task task2 = new Task(() => { ... ; return sum });
>
>    task2.Start();
>
>    task1.Wait() 
>  
>    Console.WriteLine("Result 1: {0}", task1.Result);
>
>    task2.Wait() 
>
>    Console.WriteLine("Result 2: {0}", task2.Result);`

Try this. Here you need to start both the task before calling the console.writeline.